# Retrieve changefeeds of rethinkDB if node server crashes

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript, job-queue

I have a meteor app where user can insert or update into rethink db table and I am watching the change feeds from a node worker and pushing it in rethink-node-job-queue.

Now if somehow my node-worker crashes sometimes , I will loose those changes or I will be unable to track the changes.

Is there a way I can store the changes somewhere or something like that so that  I could retrieve those changes after the node server restarts ?

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Has anyone ran into this thought ? ever?

Answer (score 0):

RethinkDB doesn't have built-in support for persistent or resumeable changefeeds.

In many situations, if you have an `updatedAt` field in your data, keeping track of the last received change can help reboot the changefeed. For example you might do:

```
r.table('foo')
 .between(lastEvent.updatedAt, r.maxval, {index: 'updatedAt', leftBound: open})
```